# Is a smaller object better for the framerate

Tags: animation

I was wondering if having a smaller object would cause the frames to drop less when animating and if so what are the drawbacks.
I have a background that is really big so i decided to ask this to know how to keep the frame rate from dropping too low.

i am using blender render to do this and i am using a castle as the background.
i just used the scale button to make the background bigger so i would not have to constantly scale down the characters that go in it.
i have used a few methods of making the frame rate higher such as using simplify and turning off shadows.

Comment: What do you mean big big as in absolute size in scene units? Also where are you playing this animation, is it an external game engine, viewport, Cycles Render, Blender Game Engine? Please edit your question and provide more info. Absolute size should have little effect in frame rate, geometry complexity should play a bigger role for animations, onscreen display size could affect framerate though.

Comment: ok i can do that

Comment: If you are rendering using Blender Internal  Render then frames are never 'dropped'. It can take longer to render if the scene is more complex, but framerate is kept constant because it is a pre-rendered animation, Also absolute object size has no influence in performance, only object complexity, and apparent onscreen display size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a large mesh zoomed out would be almost exactly the same as a scaled down mesh zoomed in. The scaling usually doesn't effect framerate, the complexity of the objects and amount of objects on screen are the two big things that effect the playback rate. If you're having trouble with playing back at the framerate you want, try putting things in different layers and working on each piece separately, then render them all together.